# Access object with dynamic key in Typescript

Tags: angular, object, typescript, interface

I have trouble accessing a property in a simple object when using dynamic key in brackets notation. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DisplayFeederService } from '../../services/display-feeder/display-feeder.service';

interface IData {
  [key: string]: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'display',
  templateUrl: './display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display.component.css']
})
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {
  measurementValue: any;
  measurementType: any;
  private typesTable: IData = {
    vdc: 'DC Volt'
  };

  constructor(private displayFeederService: DisplayFeederService) {
    this.displayFeederService.displayData$.subscribe(data => {
      this.measurementValue = data.val;
      this.measurementType = this.typesTable[data.type];
      console.log(this.typesTable, data.type, this.typesTable[data.type])
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In console.log I am getting this:

> Object {vdc: "DC Volt"} "vdc" undefined

So my object is valid, the dynamic key is correct but synatx object[dynamic key] is not working for me. If I try to access it like this this.typesTable['vdc'] it works but it's not what I want because in the future I will have more dynamic keys.

Can you please guide me to the right direction? 
Thanks

Comment: What is the return type of `data.type`?

Comment: update the post with service code and sample json that your service returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem in my case was that even if in developer tools console it was appearing as "vdc", my microcontroller was sending "vdc\n". A whitespace made me loose half of my hair. Thanks everybody.